# How to interpret the pvalue cutoff parameter from the dmrff package

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Concept question. The parameter `p.cutoff` description of `dmrff.meta()` function from `dmrff` package is the following:

> p.cutoff: Unadjusted p-value cutoff for membership in a candidate DMR

Does this mean a CpG must have a p value above that threshold to be used or part of a region? Or does it mean that the region should have a p value above that threshold (no matter which CpG that are part of that regions is)?

If an agnostic approach was to be considered, then all CpG used to identify regions, should this parameter be 1 instead of 0.05?

I tried both parameters, the results are quite similar. It is the concept I do not understand (even after reading the paper where the package is explained), it goes beyond my knowledge.